# ADB pull completion

Tags: android, python, adb

I'm working on a python script that does a adb pull command from the device. If I pull large .apk files, is there a way to find out how long it takes to complete the pull?

A sample pull:

```
      ./adb pull /data/app/com.rovio.angrybirdsstarwars.ads.iap-1.apk
```

This took sometime to finish before which my next command started even after a sleep(4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how bout calling

```
file_name = "/data/app/com.rovio.angrybirdsstarwars.ads.iap-1.apk"
cmd = "adb shell ls -l %s"%file_name #stat doesnt work i dont think
file_size = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split()[3]
usb2_xfer = 4603904.0 #4496 KB/s  (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=882608)
print "EST TIME:%0.2f secs"%(file_size/usb2_xfer)
```

you may need to adjust usb2_xfer ... also ensure your device is running in usb 2.0 not 1.1 (or it will be much slower ... see the link i got the download speed from)

this assumes that you are connected to the device via usb ... if you are connected over network maybe download a small txt file to get the download speed ....

if you are calling the command with os.system it should just block until the command finishes

```
print "Start Command!"
os.system("adb pull ...")
print "Command Finished!!"
```

if you are calling with Popen

```
print "start command"
p = subprocess.Popen("adb pull ...",stdout = subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout,stderr = p.communicate() # you could do p.wait() if you dont care about output
print "Command Finished!"
print stdout
print stderr
```

Comment: In that case is it possible to wait until this command finishes execution? before I can proceed to the next one

Comment: I initially used p = os.popen(cmd,"r"). This seems to work now os.system("adb pull ..."). There is a wait on this command